# logon to specific OU using Directoryservices

Tags: active-directory, directoryservices

I'm having trouble logging in to a specific OU in my ConsoleApp. I guess my LDAP string is incorrecct somehow, these are some output samples from my Test-App

This works fine

```
Path: LDAP://my.domain User: DOMAIN\user Pass: mypass
DOMAIN\user = Autenticated
```

But none of these

```
Path: LDAP://my.domain, ou=myou, dc=my, dc=domain User: user Pass: mypass

Path: LDAP://my.domain/ou=myou User: user Pass: mypass

Path: LDAP://my.domain/ou=myou User: DOMAIN\user Pass: mypass
```

They work in VBS though.. am I getting something all wrong or is it the AD guys that has to do something with my account? All I get is unknown user och wrong password.

They all work, if I leave out the "ou" part, conenctiong to my.domain is a breeze..

Regards

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish. It's not possible to "log in to an OU"

Comment: Hi Brian, no I know. But I want to update some Person objects but work only with the objects in the specific OU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LDAP path should be something like:

```
LDAP://servername/ou=MyOU,dc=my,dc=domain
```

(you need to provide the **server name** that you want to use as DC - as your Domain Controller)

or:

```
LDAP://ou=MyOU,dc=my,dc=domain  (for server-less binding)
```

You **cannot** specify a username/password to use right in the LDAP string. If you need that, you'll need to find another way to provide those credentials (like picking the right overloaded constructor for `DirectoryEntry` which allows you to specify a username/password to use for connecting to AD).

**Update:**

I think you should change your code to work like this:

```
string adPath = "LDAP://ou=myou,dc=my,dc=domain"; 
string adUser = "myuser";
string adPass = "mypass"; 

// you might need to play around with the "AuthenticationTypes" to get it to work
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(adPath, adUser, adPass, AuthenticationTypes.None);  

DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry); 

searcher.Filter = @"(objectClass=Person)";
```

I'm not sure if a LDAP string like this will work:

```
string adPath = "LDAP://my.domain/ou=myou,dc=my,dc=domain";
```

I vaguely remember I had to use a **server name** (not a domain name) to get this to work - something like this:

```
string adPath = "LDAP://dc01.my.domain/ou=myou,dc=my,dc=domain";
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, what I'm trying to do in my "real application" is connecting like this, but with no luck..

string adPath = "LDAP://my.domain, ou=myou, dc=my, dc=domain";
            string adUser = "myuser"
            string adPass = "mypass";
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(adPath);
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            searcher.Filter = @"(objectClass=Person)";
            entry.Username = adUser;
            entry.Password = adPass;

Comment: @elwis: your LDAP path is definitely not good - loose that `my.domain` at the beginning - that'll never work that way....

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can't get it to work though, if i skip the "ou" part of my LDAP urls they all work. And in VBScript they work even with the "OU" part, so I think the LDAP url is correct. I'll just have to rewrite my app as a script instead, thnaks for helping.

Comment: Can you post the actual name of the OUs in the path? Perhaps something needs to be escaped.

Comment: A good nights sleep was the trick. I noted a very unfriendly little character that had sneaked into my LDAP path in my config file. Thank you!